# RNDateTimePicker change date format from MM/dd/yy to anything else

Tags: javascript, react-native

how can I change the display format of `RNDateTimePicker`?

Once click the date, the date picker will pop up, after select, the display date format is **"MM/dd/yy"**. I want to change it to **"dd/MM/yyyy"** since it is the date format I use on the other screen.
I cannot find the solution for now, even on the documentation.

[image: Here the display date]

```
<RNDateTimePicker
    mode="date"
    value={upTargetStartDate}
    minimumDate={new Date()}
    onChangeText={(text) => setUpTargetStartDate(text)}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker#dateformat-optional-windows-only), you need to add  `dateFormat` property into your `RNDateTimePicker` component and pass your desire date's format which in your case is: `day month year`.

```
<RNDateTimePicker
  mode="date"
  dataFormat="day month year"    // --------> added here
  value={upTargetStartDate}  
  minimumDate={new Date()}
  onChangeText={(text) =>
  setUpTargetStartDate(text)
  }
/>
```

You can also change the format with simple javascript's methods:

```js
const wrongFormat = "12/20/21"

const [month, day, year] = wrongFormat.split("/")

const correctFormat = `${day}/${month}/${year}`

console.log(correctFormat)
```

Comment: as in documentation <RNDateTimePicker dateFormat="dayofweek day month" /> is only for window only, not working on my ios simulator. nothing change

Comment: so, what about the second solution? @zackazha

Comment: i dont find any...but if i add more width in my code, it become MMM dd, yyyy...thats all...the 2nd one technically what i've done b4 this...but i just wonder why such famous library dont have a simple date format..huhu

Comment: yes, this feature must be planned with the library itself, by the way, you can customize the output on the `onCahngeText`. you can do it with a simple **split** method and so on @zackazha